# vincular reservas de Booking y Despegar a mi web app de Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un cliente a quien le he realizado una web app basado en Codeigniter. Básicamente, sirve para un control de las reservas que realizan los clientes. El problema es la "superposición" de reservas, es decir, se realizan reservas en las famosas plataformas como Booking.com o Despegar.com y lo que mi cliente quiere es que las reservas realizadas en las mismas se vinculen a la web app y así, evitar el embrollo de que se realicen reservas superpuestas. Cómo se logra?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y casi que basada en opiniones, checa [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurren 2 maneras:

1 - Revisa si Booking.com y Despegar.com tienen api para compartir información de los alojamientos, si la tienen, crea en codeigniter alguna tarea que mantenga esa información sincronizada en tu base de datos.

2 - Utilizar web scraping para sacarle la información a las cuentas de booking y despegar de manera no oficial, este método puede ser no factible si para logearse se require pasar por un captcha. Para hacer cosas así he usado Selenium Web Driver con java.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo sin embargo te recomiendo no responder a preguntas mal planteadas que no siguen los lineamientos de [ask], ya que eventualmente terminan cerradas

Comment: En realidad la respuesta me dio bastantes ideas para seguir con el proceso que estoy buscando.

Comment: Oh, disculpa, no sabía que estaba mal planteada, es que como he trabajado antes en ese rubro entiendo el problema que se le presenta, y entiendo la manera de resolverlo, su aplicación en codeigniter tiene base de datos y su manera de mostrar las cosas, el objetivo es ir a las otras fuentes de información y traerse esas reservas hacia la base de datos propia.

Comment: No te preocupes, estuvo genial tu respuesta!

Comment: @mcalonga a la orden entonces :)

Comment: El detalle para que consideres a futuro @mcalonga es que no tienes dudas puntuales y las respuestas estarán basadas en opiniones lo cual generará el cierre de tu pub.

Comment: Respeto lo que dice usted señor @Aprendiz, porque no conozco mucho de las reglas, pero debo agregar que se entiende perfectamente el problema. Claro mi opinión es subjetiva, ya que he trabajado en ese rubro.

Comment: Para que las cosas se comprendan mejor @JuanCarlosEstradaNieto mira [answer], esto que les comento a ambos es con la intención de apoyarlos y que sigan participando en la comunidad; también ayudaría mucho hagan el [tour], pese a que tu comprendas la pub. toma en cuenta que las preguntas no solo deben sernos útiles o comprensibles a nosotros sino al resto de la comunidad que la consulte

Comment: Después de leer el enlace que me envió Sr. @Aprendiz , quizá usted considera que le falta contexto a la pregunta, poner en contexto a las personas que no son afines al tema. No se me ocurre otra cosa. Me mantengo contestando porque igual me interesa comprender mejor las reglas.